# Assigning weights to the values externally in MongoDB using Java

Tags: mongodb

This is how I could create index with different weights in ***Mongo Shell***.

```
             db.blog.ensureIndex(
                 {
                   content: "text",
                   keywords: "text",
                   about: "text"
                 },
                 {
                   weights: {
                              content: 10,
                              keywords: 5,
                            },
                   name: "TextIndex"
                 }
               )
```

This is how I created Index for the fields using ***Java***.

```
    BasicDBObject index = new BasicDBObject();
        index.put("content", "text");
        index.put("keywords", "text");
        index.put("about", "text");

collection.ensureIndex( index, "TextIndex");
```

How do I assign weights using the `Java` driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning weights to the indexed fields from `Java`:

```
    BasicDBObject index = new BasicDBObject();
    index.put("content", "text");
    index.put("keywords", "text");
    index.put("about", "text");
    BasicDBObject weights = new BasicDBObject("content", 10).append("keyword", 5);
    BasicDBObject options = new BasicDBObject("weights", weights).append("name", "TextIndex");
    collection.createIndex(index,options);
```

Comment: could you please suggest me some useful links regarding the above problem to be solved in ElasticSearch.

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html

Comment: Please give a solution for the below link:         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690620/node-discovery-disabled-in-elastic-search