# "Node Discovery Disabled" in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I used below Java code on UBUNTU and I am getting  "Node Discovery Disabled". Because of this I am not able move forward.

Could anyone please help me out solving this problem.

```
    public static JestClient JestConfiguration(){

    // Configuration
    ClientConfig client = new ClientConfig.Builder("http://localhost:9200")
                              .multiThreaded(true).build();

    System.out.println("\nclient configured via:- "+client);

    // Construct a new Jest client according to configuration via factory

    JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
    factory.setClientConfig(client);
    System.out.println("\nJestClientFactory Via:-"+factory);

    JestClient jestClient = factory.getObject();
    System.out.println("\njestClient via:-"+jestClient);

    //jestClient.shutdownClient();
    return jestClient;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what version you are using.  I am using 0.1.2 and the factory I have only has a *setHttpClientConfig* method.  So I used the **HttpClientConfig** instead, which extends **ClientConfig**. That point aside, the builder has two methods you'll want:

- discoveryEnabled
- discoveryFrequency

These set node node discovery and how frequently to poll.

```
HttpClientConfig httpClientConfig = new HttpClientConfig.Builder("http://localhost:9200") 
        .discoveryEnabled(true)
        .discoveryFrequency(10l, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .multiThreaded(true)
        .build();

JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
factory.setHttpClientConfig(httpClientConfig);
```